# Correct way to say linear dependence/independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$S=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots , v_n\}$ is a subset of a vector space $V$ over field $\mathbb{F}$.

Which is the correct way to describe $S$? $S$ is linearly dependent/independent or vectors of $S$ are linearly dependent/independent.

And why?

Comment: Personally I say S is a linearly (in)dependent set.

Comment: The second option is appropriate, why because we talk about linear (in)dependence of vectors, not sets. What you should use really depends on what you find convenient and what people around you can understand. Not a big deal IMO.

Comment: But many textbooks also write S is a linearly dependent set etc right?

Comment: They may do, perhaps because it is shorter to write "S is linearly dependent" than "vectors of S are linearly dependent".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We define Basis of a vector space  as a maximal linearly independent set. So perfectly alright to call a *set* as being  linearly (in)dependent.  Humans are good at resolving ambiguities when  the "abuse of terminology" is systematic.  No need to get unduly worried. We routinely talk of roots of a polynomial $f(x)$ even though we mean roots of the *polynomial equation*, namely $f(x)=0$.

English grammar rules  state that "My husband and I ..." is the correct way, but nobody got confused with the variation "me and my husband ..."

Comment: So it is actually vectors of S are linear dependent/linear independent,but usually people prefer saying S is linear dependent/independent.Most of them are fine with it so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Your comment about English grammar is nonsense. One says "with me", not "with I" because "with" is a preposition and the pronoun is the object of a preposition. "with my husband and I" is incorrect if you are fastidious about such things, and "with my husband and me" is correct. Or "with me and my husband". On the other hand, one says "I saw that" and thus "My husband and I saw that.", using "I", not "me" because it's the _subject_ of a verb.

Comment: @Michael Hardy. Quite likely what I wrote about grammar is nonsense as you say. I thank you for your lesson in grammar.   The point I was trying to make was mathematical statements of slightly inaccurate grammar need not be   of concern as far as many people use that inaccurate formulation.  People will understand it correctly.  Thank you.